# Setting alignment on QtDesigner but software does not comply

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer, pyuic

I've been using QtDesigner for some time already but now I got a problem. For some widgets (a label and a groupbox) I set the alignment preferences and both in the QtDesigner and the preview screen I get what I wanted but when I run the code it does not comply to what I've just set. I've already check that I saved before running the code, that it is the same file and everything, all other changes I do in Designer the software complies except for these two.

Screen from Designer:
[image]

Screen from code:
[image]

Thanks for any incoming help!

Comment: Which **specific** versions of Qt Designer and PyQt are you using?

Comment: QtDesigner 4.8.7 and Pyqt4